# How to mock transactions in rust with sqlx?

Tags: rust, rust-sqlx

I'm currently building an application with `actix-web` and `sqlx`. What I've build as an architecture is very similar to [this source](https://github.com/launchbadge/sqlx/tree/master/examples/postgres/mockable-todos).

This is basically a trait wrapping the db access, so far so good. But this assumes every single method will get a connection from the pool and execute it. There's no way to share a connection for a transactional workflow (e.g. SELECT FOR UPDATE ... process ... UPDATE).

With which achitecture or library could I achieve this?

Comment: You could consider not doing SQL mocks in the first place. I much prefer having a set of test data setup scripts and using a real database service. That avoids all of the problems of having a mock that is out of touch with reality. Sure, this is integration testing. But this is SQL, it expects to be going out of process in the first place.

Comment: @ZanLynx Problem is that then I cannot even test things like register_user_exists_test. Like mocking that user_repo will return 1 user. Yes I could test the service layer with SQL mocks. But starting testcontainers for such simple tests takes enormous time. Also not upper layer, every single one will require a db to run

Comment: Don't destroy the DB container for every test! Geez. Test setup scripts drop the tables and rebuild it in milliseconds.

Comment: Not on every test, but there’s a reason we’ve integration and unit tests. The logic that a user shall not be registered when the username is taken should run as a unit test, without needing a test db.